# Ativar ou maximizar janela de programa

Tags: java, cmd, batch, selenium-webdriver, vbscript

Tenho um programa em JAVA que utiliza o Selenium Web Driver para acessar algumas páginas e imprimi-las. Eu imprimo simulando as teclas Ctrl+P e depois Enter.

**O problema:**
São varias páginas e várias impressões, quando chega na próxima impressão pode acontecer do Adobe estar atrasado e estar aberto por cima do navegador, o que impossibilita imprimir clicando nas teclas.

**A solução:**
Gostaria de saber como ativar a janela do chromedriver.exe ( que é o programa que permanece aberto ).
Pode ser uma solução em JAVA que a partir do nome do exe ou janela do Windows ative a janela.
Pode ser um comando do Selenium que faz o driver ficar em primeiro plano.
Pode ser um comando em .BAT ou .VBS.

Qualquer opção vai ser de grande ajuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Em VBS é possível usando o código:**

---

> - Update: *para **ativar** e também **maximizar** a janela de programa*

---

```vbs
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate "chromedriver"
                            'usando sendkey para maximizar janela via teclas ::
objShell.SendKeys ("% ")    'update /teclas: alt==[%]+espaço==[ ] 
WScript.Sleep 000000000999  'update /sleep/timeout > 1 segundo
objShell.SendKeys ("x")     'update /tecla: x (maximizar janela)
```

---

**Para chamar o código:**

**<kbd>`"%Windir%\System32\CScript.exe" //nologo "Show_Active.vbs"`</kbd>**

Ou num **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** que cria o **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)** e monitora se o **Adobe** esta aberto, se caso positivo, 
chama a janela **chromedriver.exe** para primeiro plano:

```vbs
@echo off 

>"%temp%\Show_Active.vbs"^
 (
  echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
  echo/ objShell.AppActivate "chromedriver"
  echo/
  echo/ objShell.SendKeys ^("%% "^)        'update /para maximizar janela/
  echo/ WScript.Sleep 000000009999         'update /para maximizar janela/
  echo/ objShell.SendKeys ^("x"^)          'update /para maximizar janela/
 )

set _Run_CScript="%Windir%\System32\CScript.exe" //nologo
set _Show_Active=%_Run_CScript% "%temp%\Show_Active.vbs"

:_loop_:

:: para sair do looping quando a aplicação n estiver mais rodando :: 
>nul ( tasklist | find /i "chromedriver" || goto :eof )
>nul ( timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul & tasklist | find /i "AcroRd32.exe"
) && ( start "" /b %_Show_Active% ) >nul

goto :_loop_:
```

---

**Obs.:** Para usar um **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** que cria um **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)**, é necessário usar **[escape](/questions/tagged/escape)**, (como  o **^**)<kbd>**[`quando os caracteres`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)**</kbd> **[especiais](/questions/tagged/especiais)** não estiverem entre aspas:

`•` **Exemplo:**
  **<kbd>`^(, ^), ^{, ^}, ^&, ^>, ^<,  ^|, etc...`</kbd>**

`•` **Mais exemplos**  <kbd>**[`nesse link!`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)**</kbd>